# What is the general name for this particular game mechanic?

Tags: terminology, mechanics

I'm hoping to find a common general terminology for a mechanic I have encountered in several board games.

As an example, here's an excerpt from the rules for [The King's Dilemma](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/245655/kings-dilemma):

> At the end of your voting turn, if you are now the player with the **most Power [tokens] on your Vote** (no matter which side you chose), you **immediately** take the **Leader token**. Do **not** take the Leader token if you only **equal the highest bidder**’s amount of Power [tokens].

The general idea is that, if you have (say) 3 tokens on the space I want to control, it's not enough for me to put 3 of my own tokens on it; I have to put 4 or more to be in control. And if I do put 4 tokens on it (thereby gaining control), it's not enough for you to then add a 4th token of your own—you'd need to bring your total number of tokens up to 5 or more to regain control.

Is there a general term for this mechanic?

Comment: I had a look around and couldn't find a name for the mechanism. I agree that it shows up in plenty of places (e.g. the Longest Road and Largest Army cards from Catan). If I had to name it, I'd pick something like "Must Overtake the Leader" I guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **first in wins**.

See for example [this article on game design](https://kevingnunn.com/2014/05/16/bottom-up-scoring/)

> **First in wins.**  Markers placed later are considered to fall behind those placed earlier.  The only way a later player can get ahead is to exceed the previous count. This is generally best if the game has a start player disadvantage.

This is in a broader class of tie-breakers favoring efficiency, which one author categorizes as [epsilon tie-breakers](https://kanga.nu/%7Eclaw/blog/categories/game-design/index-1.html):

> The efficiency argument and even the game balance factor are a restatement of the epsilon argument addressed above. The game balance point is perhaps a little more subtle, but in essence is the same as the many majority/plurality games which state that the first one in is the default winner of the contest (eg Medieval Merchant, Die Neuen Entdecker, etc): another phrasing of epsilon.

(which I found interesting because of the default formulation of this rule: "first one in", a form of "first in wins")

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Is there any other source that confirms that this phrase is used by others as well?

Comment: Not that I could find. The term (and its opposite) are also used in concurrency programs like signal passing and databases -- that's where the rest of the hits go. But really, it seems like a relatively obvious/shallow mechanic, at least as far as needing a name goes (obviously it can lead to deep strategic choices), so (re)using a straightforward descriptive tag seems logical. It was the term that came to mind when I entered my search (so I searched for it in quotes).

Comment: @GregMartin A similar mechanic that is regularly used in a lot of other games (usually in things like attack systems) is known as "Defender Wins".